# How to find articles in Wikipedia Windows 8 App?

Tags: windows-8, wikipedia

I just used Windows 8 for the very first time yesterday.  I can see that Microsoft has changed how a number of things are done.  Most of the time, a quick Google search will answer my questions.

However, I'm stuck on something simple.  I downloaded the Wikipedia Windows 8 App.  When I run it, I see lists of "Featured Picture" and "Featured Articles".  I can click on these links to see various articles and it seems to work fine.

The problem that I'm having here is that I don't see any place where I can search for articles.  Suppose I want to see an article about "Abraham Lincoln", for instance.  How do I direct the app to search for and show me this article?

I do not have a touch-screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia app for Windows 8 and Windows RT tablets](http://blog.wikimedia.org/2012/10/26/wikipedia-app-for-windows-8-and-windows-rt-tablets/) from Wikimedia blog:

> The app integrates with Windows 8′s global search widget, which can be used both to search while in the application and to launch the app — select Wikipedia from the search providers when doing any search and you’ll pop over to us.
>
> On a laptop or desktop device with a keyboard, you can simply start typing to begin a search, just like on Windows’ Start screen.

To open the search “charm” using a mouse (from [An Introduction to Charms in Windows 8: What They Are & How to Use Them](http://www.howtogeek.com/114341/an-introduction-to-charms-in-windows-8-what-they-are-how-to-use-them/)):

> Move your mouse cursor to the top or bottom right corner of the screen, then move the cursor up or down towards the transparent charm icons that appear in the middle of your screen.

Comment: Yep. This is why I hate Windows 8. Everything has been changed. Anyway, excellent answer svick +1.

Comment: @Ace, I suppose that the ultimate question here is whether or not the change will be seen as an improvement once everyone gets used to it.

Comment: @RisingStar, I agree. Eventually, once people get used to it, perhaps it will be an improvement. However, Windows 8 is a pretty drastic change. I would have thought Microsoft would have slowly introduced all the new "features". We'll see how it does.